# Evaluate $\int \frac{e^x+\ln x}{e^x+x^x} dx $

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int \frac{e^x+\ln x}{e^x+x^x} dx $$

Now, I am not quite sure how to evaluate this one . I have tried dividing both side with $e^x$ to try to simply it in a way . Also, I was looking at the derivative of $x^x=x^x(\ln x+1)$ and I was thinking maybe I can write it in some way to then use a substitution, but no luck. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: [It doesn't look doable](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28e%5Ex%2Bln+x%29%2F%28e%5Ex%2Bx%5Ex%29&dataset=).

Comment: It is quite strange, I found it in my textbook while I was doing some practice . Maybe they  made a mistake .....

Comment: Either that, or multiplying the numerator & denominator by just the right function - which WA didn't spot - makes it trivial.

Comment: Any ideas on where  I should  look ?

Comment: It's 'non-doability' may have something to do with the fact that $$\int x^x$$ cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical notation.

Comment: I would add a tetration term to make the integral even more interesting.